# Binding ComboBox to DataTable (WinForms c#)?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, datatable

I have a method which populates my `ComboBox` from a `DataTable`:

```
public string populateCompanyTransSellingEntityLookUp(ref System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox Combo, string Id, Contract Contract)
    {
        SqlCommand _comm = new SqlCommand();
        _comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Id);
        _comm.CommandText = "SELECT [name] FROM dbo.fnGetList(@id) ORDER BY [name]; ";   
        _comm.Connection = _conn;
        _comm.CommandTimeout = _command_timeout;

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            SqlDataReader myReader = _comm.ExecuteReader();
            dt.Load(myReader);

            Combo.DataSource = dt;
            Combo.DisplayMember = "name";

            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                if (dr["name"].ToString() == Contract.Company_Name.ToString())
                {                        
                    Combo.Text = dr["company_int_name"].ToString();
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Unable to populate Company Name LookUp");
        }


        return "";
    }
```

I'm passing my saved value `Contract.Company_Name` into the forEach loop to find my required  `SelectedItem` from the `DataTable`. The `ComboBox` is populated with my DataTable values from `Combo.Datasource =dt;` but my selected item isn't being set. The code compiles without exception. If I remove `Datasource = dt;, the`SelectedItem`is set no problem. Why is the`Datasource`overriding my`SelectedItem` and is there something I've missed with my binding?

Thanks all

Comment: set ValueMember like this: Combo.ValueMember = "name";

Comment: Still not fixed unfortunately...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Combo.SelectedItem = dr;
```

Comment: Fixed. Took SelectedItem out all together and set  Combo.Text = dr["company_int_name"].ToString(); within the forEach. Not sure why the SelectedItem wouldn't bind? Edited code in question :)

Comment: In my opinion this is a ugly way to accomplish your task. You better should use SelectedValue Property. And you should think about a IList<myObject> instead of a DataTable. It is easier to handle in complex cases. For example you can use Lambda Statements.

Answer (score 0):

At first you have to set the valueMember for sure. Then you can set the selectedValue Property instead of SelectedItem. The Item is one datasource record. So in your case it would be `SelectedItem = dr`! But iam not sure this is working.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use `SelectedValue`, then you don't need to loop through values "manually".

Also you don't need to use "heavy-weight" `DataTable` where you need just a collection of string values.

```
private IEnumerable<string> LoadNames(string id)
{
    var query = "SELECT [name] FROM dbo.fnGetList(@id) ORDER BY [name]";

    using (var connection = new SqlConnection("connectionString")
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection)
    {
        // 36 is the size of the VarChar column in database(use your value)
        command.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.VarChar, 36).Value = id;

        connection.Open();
        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            var names = new List<string>();
            while(reader.Read())
            {
                names.Add(reader.GetString(0));
            }

            return names;
        }
    }
}


public void Populate(ComboBox combobox, string id, Contract contract)
{
    combobox.DataSource = LoadNames(id);
    combobox.SelectedValue = contract.Copmpany_Name.ToString();
}
```

Few things to notice:

1. Dispose all objects which dealing with external resources (`SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader`)
2. Create `SqlParameter` with precise information about the type, for strings is important to provide size of the column in database. This information will improve SQL query performance on server side.
3. Don't pass combobox as a reference, `populate` method does not create new instance but only consume the given `ComboBox` instance.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help, I edited the code given that my problem was much more trivial.

```
public string populate_comboBox(ref System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox Combo)
    {
        SqlCommand _comm = new SqlCommand();

        //edited for a simple one column sql query 
        _comm.CommandText ="SELECT [Column] FROM dbo.SQL_Table ORDER BY [Column];";
        //MUST open sql connection to DB 
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(global_DB_String_Connection);
        conn.Open();
        _comm.Connection = conn;

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            SqlDataReader myReader = _comm.ExecuteReader();
            dt.Load(myReader);

            Combo.DataSource = dt;
            Combo.DisplayMember = "ColumnName";

            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                //populates the combo box with query results
                Combo.Text = dr["ColumnName"].ToString();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ComboBox Populate method has failed! ");
        }
        conn.Close();
        return "";
    }
```